# Import plotly.plotly

Tags: pandas, plotly

I am just trying to `import plotly.plotly as py` per this tutorial:https://plot.ly/~Dreamshot/9199/import-plotly-plotly-version-/#/ but I am getting the following error, not sure why?

```
0 from plotly import exceptions, files, session, tools, utils
---> 31 from plotly.api import v1, v2
     32 from plotly.basedatatypes import BaseTraceType, BaseFigure, BaseLayoutType
     33 from plotly.plotly import chunked_requests

ImportError: cannot import name 'v1'
```

Comment: Do you have the same version of plotly as in the tutorial?

Comment: No, but not sure why that would matter? - for this situation just importing plotly.plotly , it works in idle,  not in jupyter notebook. sorry did not say that earlier.

Comment: hello, it ened up working (importing plotly.plotly) when i did "conda install plotly" not pip... :)